# Error in as.data.frame.default (data) cannot coerce class "formula" to a data.frame

Tags: r, replication, finance, stock

My code looks as follow:

```
    get_postcoefs <- function(portfo){
      my_dat <- prerank_betas %>%
        filter(portfo == portfo) %>%
        lm(ret ~ ewr, my_dat) %>% 
        coef %>% 
        as.list %>% 
        as_data_frame
}
```

And when I want to apply this function in the next step with this code

```
postrank <- prerank_betas %>%
  group_by(portfo) %>%
  do(get_postcoefs(.$portfo))
```

The data frame which I use looks as follows:

```
dput(head(prerank_betas, 10))

structure(list(permco = c(3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13), pre_beta = c(0.754759259550561, 
    0.631020855428056, 0.963497668377108, 1.42359914669436, 1.88321141160762, 
    0.137054776055511, 1.04141132820461, 0.170163365604386, 1.07633721793778, 
    1.05016503010496), ret = c(0.021630734879652, 0.00867405735757635, 
    0.0157192335910029, 0.0163030885650139, 0.017402600558639, 0.0182427638210356, 
    0.015755719798324, 0.0348026989282579, 0.0120230854319578, 0.016944221076395
    ), me = c(12.3938081896552, 603.599033139535, 36.6372490671642, 
    20.481490497076, 2918.12852836134, 1.89075555555556, 1.21730113636364, 
    5.5216014957265, 116.021340472028, 8.22907327586207), ewr = c(0.454914743929347, 
    0.65175605642766, 1.04015768854358, 1.54966348955938, 1.46542203513179, 
    0.874404877119168, 0.934768449855933, 0.296266764535612, 0.949971716508229, 
    1.31022003302531), beta_rank = c(3L, 3L, 5L, 8L, 10L, 1L, 6L, 
    1L, 6L, 6L), portfo = c(4L, 10L, 6L, 5L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 8L, 
    3L)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
    ))
```

## A tibble: 10 x 7

```
   permco pre_beta     ret      me   ewr beta_rank portfo
    <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>     <int>  <int>
 1      3    0.755 0.0216    12.4  0.455         3      4
 2      4    0.631 0.00867  604.   0.652         3     10
 3      5    0.963 0.0157    36.6  1.04          5      6
 4      6    1.42  0.0163    20.5  1.55          8      5
 5      7    1.88  0.0174  2918.   1.47         10     10
 6      8    0.137 0.0182     1.89 0.874         1      1
 7      9    1.04  0.0158     1.22 0.935         6      1
 8     11    0.170 0.0348     5.52 0.296         1      2
 9     12    1.08  0.0120   116.   0.950         6      8
10     13    1.05  0.0169     8.23 1.31          6      3
```

I receive the following error message:

```
 Error in as.data.frame.default(data) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘"formula"’ to a data.frame
```

How do I have to adapt my code that this is working.

Comment: You may create the `lm` within `mutate`.  Also, please change the input argument to a different one than the column name 'portfo'

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! i'm not really sure what do you mean. i think the input argument needs to be portfo because its filtered by portfo. I don't understand why i receive the error message above.

Comment: What i meant is that the column names is `portfo` and your argument string is also `portfo` which leadds to a clash in evaluation within `filter`

Comment: Can you show a small reproducible example for testing and your expected output

Comment: As I noted to your response on my answer, please use `dput()` to post at least 10 observations for 2 portfolios so we can produce regression models by portfolio and answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

From the OP code it looks like the question is an attempt to run `lm()` by portfolio and create an output data frame of coefficients for all the portfolio regressions.

The code in the original post fails, as noted in the comments, because the `filter()` function contains a [quasiquotation](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/quasiquotation.html) conflict when R attempts to process the expression `portfo = portfo`.

Absent a minimal reproducible example, here's an approach with `purrr::map()` and `broom::tidy()` that runs linear models on the `mtcars` data frame.

Since we're splitting the data by `mtcars$cyl`, there is no need for the `filter()` function used in the OP.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(broom)
mtcars %>% 
     split(.$cyl) %>% 
     purrr::map(.,function(x){
          lm(mpg ~ wt, data = x) %>%
               tidy(.)
     }) -> results

# combine into a data frame
df <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,results))
# extract cyl from rownames 
df$cyl <- substr(rownames(df),1,1)
```

...and the output:

```
           term  estimate std.error statistic      p.value cyl
4.1 (Intercept) 39.571196 4.3465820  9.103980 7.771511e-06   4
4.2          wt -5.647025 1.8501185 -3.052251 1.374278e-02   4
6.1 (Intercept) 28.408845 4.1843688  6.789278 1.054844e-03   6
6.2          wt -2.780106 1.3349173 -2.082605 9.175766e-02   6
8.1 (Intercept) 23.868029 3.0054619  7.941551 4.052705e-06   8
8.2          wt -2.192438 0.7392393 -2.965803 1.179281e-02   8
>
```

### A solution with the original poster's data

After hacking up the data recently posted to have at least 5 observations per `portfo` value, a solution that processes the stock data looks like this.

```
textData <- "id permco pre_beta     ret      me   ewr beta_rank portfo
1      3    0.755 0.0216    12.4  0.455         3      1
2      4    0.631 0.00867  604.   0.652         3      1
3      5    0.963 0.0157    36.6  1.04          5      1
4      6    1.42  0.0163    20.5  1.55          8      1
5      7    1.88  0.0174  2918.   1.47         10      1
6      8    0.137 0.0182     1.89 0.874         1      1
7      3    0.755 0.0216    12.4  0.455         3      2
8      4    0.631 0.00867  604.   0.652         3      2
9      5    0.963 0.0157    36.6  1.04          5      2
10     6    1.42  0.0163    20.5  1.55          8      2
11     7    1.88  0.0174  2918.   1.47         10      2
12     8    0.137 0.0182     1.89 0.874         1      2"
```

**NOTE:** by duplicating the values and adjusting the `portfo` identifiers we can demonstrate the solution, knowing that the two models produced will have exactly the same coefficients because they have the same input data.

```
prerank_betas <- read.table(text=textData,header=TRUE)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(broom)
prerank_betas %>% 
        split(.$portfo) %>% 
        purrr::map(.,function(x){
                lm(ret ~ ewr, data = x) %>%
                        tidy(.)
        }) -> results

# combine into a data frame
df <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,results))
df$portfo <- as.numeric(gsub(".$","",rownames(df)))
df
```

...and the output:

```
           term     estimate   std.error   statistic    p.value portfo
1.1 (Intercept) 1.629081e-02 0.005291043 3.078941068 0.03696967      1
1.2         ewr 2.071675e-05 0.004884269 0.004241526 0.99681887      1
2.1 (Intercept) 1.629081e-02 0.005291043 3.078941068 0.03696967      2
2.2         ewr 2.071675e-05 0.004884269 0.004241526 0.99681887      2
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

The data frame for this code looks as follows:


`> head(prerank_betas)`

# A tibble: 6 x 7 

`permco pre_beta     ret      me   ewr beta_rank portfo
   <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>     <int>  <int>

1      3    0.755 0.0216    12.4  0.455         3      4
2      4    0.631 0.00867  604.   0.652         3     10
3      5    0.963 0.0157    36.6  1.04          5      6`

how can i adapt your code to my problem? thanks for your help!

Comment: Hello @RamonHörler. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and update your answer to include at least 2 portfolios worth of data using `dput()`, and I can adapt my answer to your data.

Comment: Hello @LenGreski, thank you very much for your help. I've just updated my original question with the dataframe i use for the calculation of the coefficients. Do you need more information from me. Thank you very much!

Comment: @RamonHörler - please use `dput()` instead of `head()` to update your question, and make sure that the data includes at least 10 observations each for 2 portfolios.